# Is there a library that can extract personal informations out of text?

Tags: nlp, data-analysis

I am looking for a library that when given text like this :

"I don't know, this wasn't the first time. But as I said I'm 45yo male now and I'd rather not do things like that again"

Will return some object containing informations like this : {"gender":"male", "age":45}

(Ideally something evolved enough that it recognizes different ways of saying it, ex: "I'm 45" / "Im 45" / "I am now 45yo",  "I turned 45 yesterday" etc

Comment: A library which does that off the shelf, very unlikely. You would probably have to collect/find some annotated data and train a model.

Comment: Probably not the answer you're looking for, but if you have some money to spend, you can create a prompt and call the openai API.

Answer (score 1):

Within NLP, the task you're looking for is identifying/detecting PII (personally identifiable information). Depending on your budget/scope, AWS offers [PII detection within Amazon Comprehend](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/how-pii.html).

Alternatively, [pii-codex](https://github.com/EdyVision/pii-codex) offers an open source solution that may meet your needs.